# I want the user to insert data in a TextBox only in a specific manner

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In a car number the format of writing will be same. For example, the Car Number is Written only in the manner: `RJ20CF2091`.

Now consider it from left to right. In the first 2 places, only alphabet should come, the next two (3rd and 4th place) should be digits only, the 5th & 6th position, only letters and the last 4 (7th, 8th, 9th & 10th) only digit.

The data in the TextBox should be exactly of size 10.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [MaskedTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox), you can provide a Mask that allows only specific sets of characters in defined positions.

Since your Input is: `2 Letters + 2 Numbers + 2 Letters + 4 Numbers`, this can be expressed, using the mask elements described in the control's [MaskedTextBox.Mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask) property, as: **`LL00LL0000`**.

Note that you also need to set the [AsciiOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.asciionly) property to `True`.

Since the input appears to only use capitol letters, you can use the **`KeyPress`** event to automatically convert to uppercase the user input:

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.KeyPress
    e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must define, *when* the validation should take place:

- When textbox losing the focus?
- For each typed letter?
- When the user hits a button, e.g. "OK"?

Then you need to define, what shoudl happen if the user input is not valid:

- Make something red?
- Show a exclamantion mark or another logo somewhere?
- Deactivate other controls?

For your actual problem, you can use Regluar expressions like this:

```
bool isValid = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("RJ20CF2091",@"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{4}");
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/4VPBXx/1)